# Retrieve remote text from server and display in a Panel

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there was a way to remotely retrieve a text file and have it display in a panel in visual studio as regular text. I am trying to use it in an app that retrieves and displays update text to you everytime you launch the application.

Comment: Also, just to be clearer, i am not looking at having it displayed in a text box rather as regular text in a panel.

Comment: Add some of your code to your question! Without it, it's hard to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the text file which is stored as a static file in a server, then you can use :

```
using System.Net;

string content = "";

using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
{
    content = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/content.txt");
}
```

To display the content inside a panel, you can use a Rich textbox or label (former is recommended, with readonly mode enabled). You cannot display text directly in a panel without the above user controls

If you really don't want to use a textbox, there are a few issues. The labels don't wrap into multiple lines by itself. You will have to write some additional code to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to remotely display it in visual studio use the web browser window and simply ask it to load your txt file. Im pretty sure its base on IE 11 it will download and display your txt file with no problems. if you want to display it in the txt editor i don't think visual studio has a way to do that built in but you can always write a little script in your preferred lang to automate the process of downloading and opening in VS.

Also you can use a source control system to automatically update the project for the latest commit if that's what you want.